# Why is my spinner not shown in Turbolinks?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks

I thought of creating a spinner which is displayed while the page is being loaded with Turbolinks.
Here is my Coffeescript:

```
startSpinner = ->
  console.log "started fetching"
  $('html').append('<div id="spinner" class="whirly"></div>')
stopSpinner = ->
  $('#spinner').remove()
  console.log "stopped fetching"


$(document).on("page:fetch", startSpinner());
$(document).on("page:receive", stopSpinner());
```

The spinner seems to show correctly if I set a breakpoint into stopSpinner (before it removes the spinner), but it is never visible otherwise. What am I missing? Are page:fetch and page:receive the wrong calls?

FYI I took the spinner from http://css-spinners.com/#/spinner/whirly/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startSpinner()` is a function *call*, not a function *reference*. jQuery's `on` wants a function reference as its second argument so you should be saying:

```
$(document).on("page:fetch",   startSpinner)
$(document).on("page:receive", stopSpinner)
```

to bind the functions to those events. Your code:

```
$(document).on("page:fetch", startSpinner());
$(document).on("page:receive", stopSpinner());
```

is trying to bind the `startSpinner` and `stopSpinner` return values to those events and that does nothing useful.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the comprehensible explaination! It is working perfectly now.